# Looping over nested objects in React

Tags: reactjs, multidimensional-array, nested-loops

please I need some help with looping through nested arrays in react... Here's the sandbox link:

https://codesandbox.io/embed/romantic-breeze-bg8om?file=/src/App.js&codemirror=1

Many Thanks

Comment: What is it that you're trying to achieve?

Comment: What have you tried and what's not working?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read through the content at the Help Center, specifically on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You're missing some important information that makes it difficult for answerers to help you, and for the question to have long-term value to future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate like that.
And you had 'name' instead of 'buildTitle' in projectsData.js (`name: "resident choices"`)

https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-bhaskara-2zrys

Comment: Questions and answers that live almost completely off-site are unlikely to be helpful to future readers since links rot and the content is less-easily available even for good links. Please have a look at the Help Center's [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) section for some guidelines on how to write a good answer that will hold up over time.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer bro, I think I've found a way around it.